# perl program for reading file contents

Tags: linux, perl

I want to write a perl program for opening a file and reading its content and the printing the number of lines, words and characters there are. I also want to print the number of times a specific word appeared in the file. Here is what I have done:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
open( FILE, "test1.txt" ) or die "could not open file $1";
my ( $line, $word, $chars ) = ( 0, 0, 0 );
while (<FILE>) {
    $line++;
    $words += scalar( split( /\s+/, $_ ) );
    $chars += length($_);
    print $_;
}
$chars -= $words;
print(
    "Total number of lines in the file:= $line \nTotal number of words in the file:= $words \nTotal number of chars in the file:= $chars\n"
);
```

As you can clearly see, I don't have any provision for taking user input of the words whose occurrence is to be counted. Because I don't know how to do it. Please help with counting of the number of occurrence part. Thank you

Comment: if your file doesn't end with a newline you're gonna miss a character.

Comment: Why `$chars -= $words` ?

Comment: @PeterR for a given line the number of characters equals the length of the line minus the number of words... considering every word is followed by a spacing character. however, as I pointed in my previous comment, it doesn't work if the line doesn't end with a newline character (it applies only to the last line of course).

Comment: @Pierre Ah, i thought they meant actual chars. This is definitely a case where id have a comment if i wrote this. I'd also handle this with chomping

Comment: have you heard of `$.`? saves you the line counting part.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I m sorry, I am a newbie to perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're doing this for learning purposes, so here is a good readable version of your problem (there might be a thousand others, because it's perl). If not, there's `wc` on the linxux command line.

Note that I'm using three argument open, it's generally better to do that.
For counting single words you'll most probably need a hash. And I used `<<HERE` docs, because they are nicer for formating. If you have any doubts, just look in the `perldoc` and ask your questions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;   # Always use this
use strict;     # ditto

my ($chars,$word_count ,%words);
{
  open my $file, '<', 'test.txt' 
  or die "couldn't open `test.txt':\n$!";
  while (<$file>){
    foreach (split){
      $word_count++;
      $words{$_}++;
      $chars += length;
    }
 }
} # $file is now closed

print <<THAT;
Total number of lines: $.
Total number of words: $word_count
Total number of chars: $chars
THAT

# Now to your questioning part:
my $prompt=  <<PROMPT.'>>';
Please enter the words you want the occurrences for. (CTRL+D ends the program)
PROMPT
print $prompt;

while(<STDIN>){
  chomp; # get rid of the newline
  print "$_ ".(exists $words{$_}?"occurs $words{$_} times":"doesn't occur")
    ." in the file\n",$prompt;
}
```

Comment: 'I did a program in which I used $wordcountinline = scalar(split(/$searchword/,$_). This works fine but it works for characters also. That is, if I enter 'j' then it finds how many times the character 'j' has occured. But your program runs fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Pranjal: you wont need the explicit `scalar` in your line. And you really should use `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: What are the 'strict' and 'warnings' used for?

Comment: @Pranjal: they both prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot, as it is said. [`Warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) warns you of several things, an adept of Perl might not be aware of, like unitialized variables or void statements. [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) ensures that all the variables you use are predeclared and disables some strange bareword and reference features, you really don't want to use if you didn't know about them. The `vars` part of `strict` is the most important one, since it catches typos in variable names.